# DAX to calculate no of days between 2 dynamic dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 date column in my table ie entrydate and exitdate and also containerno column and 1 seperate date table in power bi.

Now the case is -
I have 1 date slicer in report.

Need to count no of days in monthly basis.
Eg if my container enter in 20-nov-2020 and exitdate is 5-Dec-2020
So when we select 26-nov-2020 in my date slicer then
Required output is 6 days.
Means then my selected date will become my exitdate.
And when we select 1-dec-2020 to 10-dec-2020 then
Output is 5 days

So my entry and exit date can be dynamic based on selected date by comparing with entrydate and exitdate

Comment: Provide some sample data.

Comment: Also please show the measure you have tried so far - it might be that you are quite close to the solution and we will help you understand what was lacking.